# Update Table with a multi-criteria form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've a multi-criteria search form that searches the Top 20 records in the TblABC based on the filter's selected. The user will be assigned the record when the Assign button is clicked. This will update the ID field (currently blank) in the TblABC.

Currently stuck at the Update Statement... appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
Private Sub BtnAssign_Click()

Dim strfilter As String

'Filters the form with comboboxes

If Nz(Me.cboIndustry, "") <> "" Then
strfilter = strfilter & "([Major clusters] = '" & Trim(Me.cboIndustry) & "') AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.cboIncorp, "") <> "" Then
    strfilter = strfilter & "([Years Incorporated] = '" & Trim(Me.cboIncorp) & "') AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.cboIndustry, "") <> "" Then
strfilter = strfilter & "([Major clusters] = '" & Trim(Me.cboIndustry) & "') AND "
End If

... ...

'Assign record to User - Updates Tabel ABC

Dim strAssign As String

strAssign = "Update Top 20 * [TblABC] set [ID] = '" & Trim(Me.cboID) & "'"
strAssign = strAssign & " where " & strfilter

DoCmd.RunSQL strAssign

End Sub
```

Search button works extremely well with this. It searches for the Top 20 records from TblABC based on the filtered criteria the user chooses.

```
Private Sub BtnSearch_Click()

Dim strfilter As String 

'Filters the form with comboboxes

If Nz(Me.cboIndustry, "") <> "" Then strfilter = strfilter & "([Major clusters] = '" & Trim(Me.cboIndustry) & "') AND " End If

If Nz(Me.cboIncorp, "") <> "" Then
    strfilter = strfilter & "([Years Incorporated] = '" & Trim(Me.cboIncorp) & "') AND " End If

If Nz(Me.cboIndustry, "") <> "" Then strfilter = strfilter & "([Major clusters] = '" & Trim(Me.cboIndustry) & "') AND " End If

... ...

'Search for Top 20 records based on criteria from TblABC

Dim strwhere As String

strwhere = "Select Top 20 * from [TblABC]" 
strwhere = strwhere & " where " & strfilter

Frm.RecordSource = strwhere

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. `Dim strAssign As String is declared twice`
2. `3rd If block repeated twice and the last condtion should not have "And" suffix`

Comment: Is there any code in that procedure that truncates the last "AND"?

Comment: no there isnt, the code works well for the search button, code as above. Not sure how to go about with the Update statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `TOP n` in an `UPDATE` query. This is a rather strange requirement.

If you really must do this, you'll have to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET foo = 'bar'
WHERE table.PrimaryKeyColumn IN
(SELECT TOP 20 PrimaryKeyColumn FROM table
 WHERE <strFilter> 
 ORDER BY <sortColumn> )
```